# why does console.log output all records and not response.end - Node.js

Tags: node.js

Im a newbie with node.js and i'm trying to output some data to html.
My code works when I use console.log but not when I use response.end.
When I use response.end I only see on record while when I use console.log I get to see all the records

See my full code below:

```
var http = require('http');
var formOutput;
var WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');

// Initialize the WooCommerceAPI class
var WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    //url: 'http://example.com', // Your store url (required)
});

function handleRequest(response) {
    // GET example
    WooCommerce.get('products', function (err, data, res) {
        //console.log(res);

        //var fs = require('fs');
        //var jsonContent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4))
        var jsonContent = JSON.parse(res)

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonContent["products"].length; i++) {
            var name = jsonContent["products"][i];
             // this works well and I can output all records
            //console.log(name['title']);
            //console.log(name['id']);
            //console.log(name['sku']);
            //console.log(name['regular_price']);
            //response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            //res.end(name['id']);
            formOutput = name['regular_price'];
            //formOutput = '<h1>XYZ Repository Commit Monitor</h1>';
            //response.write();
            //Only get one record
            response.end(formOutput);
            //response.write('<html><head></head><body>');
            //response.end("test");
            //response.end('</body></html>'); 
        }
    });
        //response.end(formOutput);
    }


http.createServer(function (req, response) {
    if (response.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end();
    } else {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });   
    }

    //code here...
    handleRequest(response);
   // response.end(formOutput);

}).listen(1337, "localhost");
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:1337/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express, response.**end**() closes the communication channel after one call so only one element will be sent to the user. Don't use **end()** to send data, in your case, use `response.json()` (or `send()`) ONCE after you built the data array.

```
var dataToSend = [];
for (var i = 0; i < jsonContent["products"].length; i++) {
  // build an array of data to send here

}

response.json(dataToSend);
```

On a side note, don't use `response.end()` unless you want to end the communication explicitly. `response.json()` and `response.send()` already close the channel when needed.

Comment: Thanks ShanShan when I use response.json and response.send I get error " response.json is not a function"

Is this used whe using express.js which i'm not using

Comment: I assumed you were using express. For the `http` module, you can use `response.write` and you have to call `end()` (once) to close the connection.